# Is /dev protected by SIP?

Tags: high-sierra

So I know /dev contains all the drivers required for mouse , keyboard etc but can some dangerous malware delete the folder? Or can someone manually delete the folder with `sudo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The directory that SIP ([About System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)) covers are

> - /System
> - /usr
> - /bin
> - /sbin
> - Apps that are pre-installed with OS X

> /dev contains all the drivers required for mouse , keyboard etc

No.  These are device nodes or special files that access the hardware directly.

Device drivers are usually located in the System Library as kexts (Kernel Extensions).  See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222367/119271) for more further details.

> can someone manually delete the folder with sudo?

Yes, you can delete this folder however, it should be restored upon reboot because these nodes are *dynamically* generated as hardware is detected.  Under Linux and BSD, the command `makedev` will regenerate your devices.  `mknod` will do the same for macOS.

From the man page (`man mknod`)

> The mknod command creates device special files.

So, can malware delete or affect these files?  Possibly, but it would be counterproductive because it would need `root` access to begin with and whatever changes would be temporary at best.

Comment: SIP does prevent block-level writes to protected disks (e.g. writes to startup drive `/dev/disk` and `/dev/rdisk` devices), otherwise you could easily bypass restrictions. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

Comment: "Under Linux and BSD, the command `makedev` will regenerate your devices. `mknod` will do the same for macOS." – Actually, on almost all modern Linux distributions, `/dev` is dynamically managed by `udev`. Static `makedev` (or `MAKEDEV`) scripts haven't existed for over a decade. (Before `udev`, `/dev` was sometimes a virtual filesystem called `devfs`.) Also note that both the `udevd` daemon as well as the venerable old `MAKEDEV` scripts, simply call the `mknod` utility, and the `devfs` filesystem driver calls the `mknod` syscall.